# Spacing Between Bootstrap Columns with Backgrounds

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to build a grid like:

[image]

However, because columns use paddings instead of margins, when I add a background color the columns end up touching.

I could add another div within' each column and set the background on it, but I'm already not a fan of all of the added markup required by Bootstrap. Is there a clean way to accomplish this without adding a dozen extra elements?

#### **EDIT:**

To clarify, the grid is like a col-4, col-8... Then within' the col-8 are 3 col-4's...

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/tpyvvxou/)
[JSFiddle Link w/Wells](http://jsfiddle.net/9rpxq84o/2/) (Not a fan of the extra markup for the bg)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="well well-sm">Left Top</div>
            <div class="well well-sm">Left Bottom</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="well well-sm">Left/Middle</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="well well-sm">Right/Middle</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="well well-sm">Right Top</div>
                    <div class="well well-sm">Right Bottom</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--end row-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--end row-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">Other content...</div>
    </div>
    <!--end row-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You gotta get creative with Bootstrap. If you want an easier way, I suggest using `panels` or `wells`.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <div class="well well-sm">
  Content goes here
   </div>
</div><!--end col-->
```

[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9rpxq84o/)

Comment: THanks, but that's essentially doing exactly what I was afraid I'd have to do... Adding a div within' the column just to add a bg color. Also, this is more in-line with the grid I'm trying to accomplish. http://jsfiddle.net/9rpxq84o/2/ Just not a fan of all of the extra markup. :/

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't much added mark up required for most things in Bootstrap, except for the forms.

DEMO: https://jsbin.com/punazu/1/

To avoid additional inner elements, you can do this:

**CSS**

```
.mygrid > [class*="col-"]:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #eee;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
    z-index: -1;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.mygrid > [class*="col-"]{
    padding:15px 30px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row mygrid">

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      hello this is the content inside this column
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      hello
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      hello
    </div>    

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't address my issue since I'd have to use nested columns to build the grid in the image. See here: http://jsbin.com/yafizajuza/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a "clean" solution to your problem. We have to think that Bootstrap grid is a help to set containers for our contents, so personally i think its a bad idea to set aspect to row/cells like backgrounds. I prefer to add a div inside col-* class.

Anyway, if you think that this point means to add extra tags to your html document you could set a new  number of cells for a Bootstrap row and use col-offset-* to set proportional space between cells. If you are using Bootstrap importing Less files you could try to change the value of @grid-columns (default: 12) to a higher number and define the space between cells using col-offset-* classes as i said before. If you are importing Bootstrap CSS try to recompile it changing this variable in http://getbootstrap.com/customize/.